# Can Latch be used to store voltages?

Tags: digital-logic, latch

What if we put S=5v , R=0v and then detach the latch IC  from the circuit what will happen at Q end ?

Comment: Huh? What does happen practically then?

Comment: A latch of any type can only store its logic 1 or 0 voltage. If it is 5 volt logic that is what will be stored at Q for CMOS logic. Did you thing a digital latch could store analog values?

Comment: Closing because this a *very basic* question about what a latch does, and answering would just be reading the datasheet to the OP.  The volunteers here should be spending their time on worthwhile questions.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. Agreed, but I will leave my answer as is. OP needs to read a lot of datsheets...

Comment: you need a capacitor to persist analog voltage values

Comment: You misread the question. He's not asking about the latch's defined behavior... he's asking about it's undefined behavior when the **input** voltages are removed. Essentially, he's asking about the use of an SR latch as a Flash memory.

Comment: @DrFriedParts. Is was understood by all that the OP was referring to a 'trapped' voltage. It did not matter if it was a 'D' type latch or transparent with LE = '0'.

Comment: It's completely volatile but sure, essentially it does store _some_ voltage for only a rather quick period of time. A lot of memory devices utilize a capacitor to retain a target voltage. I advise you to do a little research on how DRAM cells are able to hold memory.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  Which datasheets are you referring to ?

Comment: The datasheet for the latch, obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A digital latch of any type can only store its logic 1 or 0 voltage.

If it is 5 volt logic that is what will be stored at Q for CMOS logic '1'. If it is 3.3 volt logic that is what will be stored at Q for CMOS logic '1'. Obviously a logic '0' will be zero volts, or millivolts at most.

Did you think a digital latch could store arbitrary analog values?

A sample-and-hold will briefly store a analog value, but the value will drop to zero volts in a (short) finite time. An ADC will latch in an analog value as a digital value of 4/6/8/12/16/18/24 or 32 bits.

The SR latch you mentioned will retain its 'state' if it is positive logic and 'S' is a logic '1' and R is logic '0' *long enough to be valid*. You mentioned 5 volts so I assume it is 5 volt CMOS logic, as TTL is seriously outdated, except some tech schools may use them. Your CMOS latch will retain its state, thus about 5 volts will remain on the Q pin.